# In PhantomJS, does page.includeJs() return anything? Could the equivalent be done synchronously via page.evaluate()?

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 2.0.0 on a Mac OS X Yosemite.

This is really two separate, but related questions:

1. Does `WebPage.includeJs()` return anything?  See code below for context.  I would like to include jQuery in a frame, figure out if some element is in the frame, and return a flag accordingly.
2. Is `page.evaluate()` called synchronously?  If so, could I synchronously include jQuery in the page, run my test, and return a flag synchronously through invocation of `page.evaluate()`?

Here's the code (I realize the variable `eventContentFound` may in fact be scoped in two separate places -- once in the invoking code, and once within the frame.  I'm merely trying to explain the idea that I would like the value from the frame instance of the variable to to be conveyed to the invoking parent scope.):

```
    var eventContentFound = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < window.frames.length; ++k) {
      page.switchToChildFrame(k);
      page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        var eventHeaderFound = page.evaluate(function() {
          var eventArr = $("tr.twSimpleTableHeadRow th[scope='col']").filter(function() { return $(this).text() == "Event"; });
          return eventArr.length > 0;
        });

        if (eventHeaderFound) {
          eventContentFound = true;
        }
      });
    }
    console.log("eventContentFound=" + eventContentFound);
```

If what I want to do cannot be done via `page.includeJs()`, then how can I accomplish the same thing otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page.includeJs()` is asynchronous, because it needs to fetch a remote JavaScript file. That is why your `console.log("eventContentFound=" + eventContentFound);` code will always show `eventContentFound=false`.

You don't need to use jQuery for such an easy query. Plain JavaScript also works:

```
var eventContentFound = false;
for (var k = 0; k < window.frames.length; ++k) {
    page.switchToChildFrame(k);
    var eventHeaderFound = page.evaluate(function() {
      var eventArr = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr.twSimpleTableHeadRow th[scope='col']", function(el) { return el.textContent.trim() == "Event"; });
      return eventArr.length > 0;
    });

    if (eventHeaderFound) {
      eventContentFound = true;
    }
}
console.log("eventContentFound=" + eventContentFound);
```

Comment: It would be nice if WebPage.open() guaranteed the availability of jQuery in the page and all of its subframes (if present).  I realize falling back to javascript is an option, but part of the rationale (for me at least) of having a batch-based mechanism for querying / processing the DOM offline is that you benefit from the glory of jQuery without actually running a browser.

Comment: We can't have everything. You could however use a local jquery file along with `page.injectJs`.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to continue including a remote script, then you won't be able to use a loop anymore. You will run into all kinds of concurrency problems with a loop like this.